Cannot find package '@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider
Getting a very strange error with AWS Cognito provider.
I stepped away from our back-end Node JS repo for a few weeks, and suddenly our sign-in endpoint is no longer working.
{
"message": {
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "Cannot find package '@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider' imported from /var/task/index.mjs",
    "trace": [
        "Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider' imported from /var/task/index.mjs",
        "    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)",
        "    at packageResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:732:9)",
        "    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:773:18)",
        "    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:887:11)",
        "    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:89:40)",
        "    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:242:28)",
        "    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:76:40)",
        "    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:75:36)",
        "    at process.runNextTicks [as _tickCallback] (internal/process/task_queues.js:60:5)",
        "    at /var/runtime/deasync.js:23:15"
    ]
},
"error": null

Situation

no other team mates using the same repo, are getting this
no code changes were made on my end
going back to a branch made weeks ago that was working fine, is also throwing this error.

What I've tried

tried with Node versions 22, 20, and 14.

tried updating that particular package, and all the other AWS packages we use.

deleted and reinstalled the node_modules

Completely deleted and re-cloned the repo


Extra Notes
This error only shows in Postman when I hit the sign-in endpoint. There are no errors when starting the server. This error does not show in my console, only in Postman.

Does the package actually exist in the relevant node_modules location? Is NODE_PATH correct? Do other AWS SDK modules load correctly?

I do see files in the node_modules/aws-sdk folder, yes. There are a bunch of imports in the entry file (Express, cors, dotenv, etc) and I get no issues from them.

OK but do you have a node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider folder and does it contain what you'd expect to see (package.json, the various dist-cjs,  dist-es folders etc)?

Yes, it contains all of those.

I'd be tempted to do some additional investigation. If you have access to the system (is it EC2?) then run node.js manually with a simple source file that imports the Cognito package. Try to investigate using the typical mechanisms, like verifying NODE_PATH.

appreciate the assistance, @jamrod.
So, I started a new node project with just the bare minimum to do an aws cognito login, and it worked! Now, just have to figure out why the main repo is failing.

Following up again. I set up a dual boot in Linux (Mint), and the same error shows there

Finally found the problem here. My .env file was incorrect. AWS keys were being overwritten.
Very misleading error message.

It may have been that you were running "npm install" in one folder then navigating away and running the script elsewhere. Without "-g" global flag (npm install -g <package_name>) npm installs packages in the node_modules/ that's relative to where "npm install" ran.
